# pcb soldering a continuous line

Tags: soldering

I am trying to solder a continuous line with a non-lead soldering wire but I ended like this. Now it's not conducting but there is no gaps between anywhere. How can I fix this?

[image]

Comment: Not sure which places you really intended to be continuous, but I see lots of places in long lines that have gaps.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Lead Free Soldering and bad looking joints](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/103778/lead-free-soldering-and-bad-looking-joints) The best answer there was "get some proper lead/tin solder!"

Comment: lead free is not conducting ? (sn/cu)

Comment: Lead free solder conducts just fine.  You just have to actually connect all the points.  It is probably simpler to use a short piece of wire rather than trying to solder all the pads in a row together.

Comment: Lead-free solder conducts fine, but it's a lot harder to use.

Comment: solder a bare wire over the pads you want to connect, rather than trying to drag a solder bead to make the connection.

Comment: Honestly, this looks like you really need to practice some more soldering with this matarial, and especially the large blobs in the top right suggest you've got a problem actually wetting the contacts. There's nothing wrong with the lead-free solder, your handiwork is just not good enough (yet)!

Answer (score 5):

Don't try to make circuits with all solder bridges.  Lay a section of bare wire along your desired connection, and solder it down.  You don't even have to hit every pad to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

The bare wire (you can use cut-off resistor or diode leads) is the best approach, but there is a technique to making solder blobs connect.

Experiment with cooling the tip on a damp sponge before dragging the solder sideways to join two existing blobs. If you get it too hot it will not join. Lead-free solder may be an advantage in this situation as it behaves more "gummy" than beautiful shiny Sn63Pb37 solder.